# Return map from background script using Promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing web-extension and I need to get a map as a reply from background script. In order to make my extension compatible with both firefox and chrome, I use Mozilla's *webextension-polyfill*.
Here is a code sample:

**front.js:**

```
var sendmsg = browser.runtime.sendMessage(1);

sendmsg.then(
    result => { handleResponse(result); },
    error => { handleError(error); });

function handleError(e)
{
   console.log("ERROR HANDLED: " + e);
}

function handleResponse(result)
{
    console.log("map size = " + result.size);  
}
```

**background.js**

```
var maptest = new Map();

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onContentMessage);

function onContentMessage(msg, sender, handleResponse)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    maptest.clear();
    maptest.set("aaa", 1);
    resolve(maptest);
  });
}
```

However, this works only in ff, in any chromium-based browser handleResponse argument is *undefined*. I have tested Promises under chrome without content-background message exchange, and it returns map correctly. Is the problem in webextension-polyfill and does anybody know, how to solve it?

Comment: You're returning a promise from `onContentMessage`. Do you need to?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am using asynchronous request to IndexedDB in background script. In fact, I'm porting extension that already works in FF, that's why I do not want to change data type using for exchange.

Comment: `Map` is not JSONifiable as you can see by running JSON.stringify(maptest). You can send `[...maptest]`

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail? It's not clear for me, what does this syntax means and how to access map object in handleResponse after receiving [...maptest] from promise.

Comment: It's ES6 spreading syntax. After receiving you simply do `new Map(data)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, both in FF and chrome! It seems, that in opposite - original version shoudn't  work in firefox )

Answer (score 0):

Solution is the following: in background script it is necessary to apply spreading operator to map object

```
push([...maptest]);
```

It converts map object to [[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ... ] array. This array can be received in content script, and it can be converted back to map object with:

```
function handleResponse(result)
{
  var mapobj = new Map(result);
```

Thank's to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the solution